# adding functionality to a textbox

Tags: asp.net, jquery, textbox

i want to load a page after a textbox looses its focus.But it not working. What is wrong in it?

```
$(function() {
    $("#txtBox").blur(function() {
        $('#LoadPage').load("Defult.aspx");
    });
});
```

Comment: Is that a typo in your page name?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your textbox's ID is set to "txtBox". Could you post the rest of the code, too?

**EDIT** Like `Nick` commented below, did you misspell `Default.aspx` as `Defult.aspx`?

Comment: yes the id is 'txtBox' for sure. what else code is needed? There is one div whose id is 'LoadPage'

Comment: @koin - you sure it isn't `"Default.aspx"`?